# Bypassing MediaRecorder for recording/processing video in Android

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder

New to Android and Java but I have a long programming background.

Supposing I want to record some video from a phone but directly manipulate the pixels while recording (before the H.264 encoding), how would I go about this?  In the Android documentation, it seems that you use the MediaRecorder class and assign it a Camera, and then it records to a file or URI.  But I want to handle the data during the capture and before the save (not save and then process).

Thanks

Comment: Yuo 'll have to look at the source code of MediaRecorder..

Comment: Everything you need seems to be in a native library.. `MediaRecorder` is just a wrapper for main operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need is in the `libmedia.so` library. There is no straight method of manipulating video frames in real time.

This should help you start thinking on the possibilities :)              http://rxwen.blogspot.in/2010/01/understanding-android-media-framework.html

You can check the source of libmedia library.